# getting installation error every time I tried to update android studio to version 3.5

Tags: android

I have tried to update android studio many times and every time after downloading and trying to install I got the following error

[image]

does anyone know what should I do ?

Comment: have you tried uninstalling and reinstalling android studio ?

Comment: It is a gradle problem, Uninstall Android studio completely adn reinstall that will fix the problem